# WebApplications (.war file) and common jar file

Tags: tomcat, war, jar

i need to deploy at Tomcat many web applications with a lot of common jars (Jersey jars). I've created WAR file without JARS and added to MANIFEST.MF eg: "Class_Path: .jar .jar". But WebApplications does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is Tomcat giving you any error message in the log?

Answer (score 2):

Place the JARs in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Then create the WAR. Dont worry about MANIFEST file.